# React Native Error: "Unable to resolve "react" from "src\screens\Main.js"

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to get an application that I designed with builderx.io to work with react native using expo. However, I could never get it to work.

[Error Message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI2yD.jpg)

[Folder Structure and my index.js file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ftor.jpg)

[Main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIP3w.jpg)

Comment: why you are exporting main.js in index,js?

Comment: I'm new to react native that is why I'm using the designer tool builder.io, and by default that is how it packages it for some reason. My interpretation of what it wants to do is redirect directly from index.js to the main.js in which I have my home screen